# Does this sentence really need a comma?

Tags: commas

"Though the technology behind a Poké Ball remains unknown and has evolved through the centuries to accommodate the diverse requirements of their creators, the basic mechanics are simple enough to understand and tend to remain constant."

So basically, I've had a random mind blank, and I've been reassessing whether specific sentences require commas or not.

I've mostly been using this website: https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp

It's been really helpful to understand all of the comma rules but how does it work in this case? According to the website I posted above, the sentence requires a comma if there's two independent clauses but 'the basic mechanics are simply enough to understand and tend to remain constant' can't really stand by itself can it? Not to mention there's no conjunction linking it.

Or even this sentence here above 'It's been really helpful to understand all of the comma rules but how does it work in this case?'. It feels like it needs a comma after the rules but 'how does it work in this case?' can't really stand by itself because it's referring to something, right?

Sorry if this isn't the right place to ask all these questions, but I'm having a huge blank space right now which is really frustrating. Maybe I'm just overthinking. Thank you to anyone who offers their assistance in advance. I appreciate it.

Comment: I'd say you ***need*** the comma after ***of their creators***. Unless you move all the text that follows to the ***front*** of the entire utterance (everything else is syntactically "parenthetical"), in which case it's just a "stylistic choice" whether to include any such punctuation.

Comment: Oh okay thanks. Is it because the first part of the sentence is a dependent clause then? I'm just trying to find the rule for when I should apply a comma and when I shouldn't.

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't have used the word "need" in a context like this. I certainly wouldn't accept the idea that there's any "absolute rule" involved here. Personally, I'm "okay" with ***[Even] though it's hot he wears a fur coat*** without a comma - but I'm sure not everyone would agree with me there.